# Add duration for reloadRowsAtIndexPaths (swift)

Tags: swift

How can i add the duration for the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths? Here is my code

```
   var indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
        var indexPath2 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 3, inSection: 0)
        var indexPath3 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)
       // self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath1,indexPath2,indexPath3], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

Comment: Try with `NSTimer.schedule....` or `UIView.animate...`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the animation duration.